# Maxwell's equations in Lorenz Gauge in terms of 4-vector potential

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, maxwell-equations

I am trying to obtain the 4-vector representation of the Maxwell's equations in the Lorenz gauge in terms of the Gaussian units, from the corresponding SI form, in particular the 0th component. The 4-vector potential (in Gaussian units) is given as $\textbf{A}^{i}=\{\phi,\textbf A\}$ and the $\phi$ part of the Lorenz gauge Maxwell's equation is given as:

$${-\nabla^{2} \phi+\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial t^2}=\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_{0}}
}$$

Now for converting to Gaussian units, I made the following changes:

$$\begin{aligned}
\phi &\rightarrow \sqrt\frac{\mu_{0}}{4\pi} \phi \\
\rho &\rightarrow \sqrt{4\pi\epsilon_{0}}
\end{aligned}
$$

This is giving me the following (in Gaussian units):

$$\Box\  \phi=4\pi c\rho$$

On consulting Griffiths and Wikipedia, I found that this was wrong, the right hand side should have been just $4\pi\rho$ instead of $4\pi c\rho$. Where did I make a mistake in this?

P.S.: $\Box$ is the d' Alembertian operator, equivalent to $\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}-\nabla^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sqrt{4\pi\epsilon_0}\phi$ in SI units transforms to $\phi$ in Gauss units, and charge density $\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi\epsilon_0}}\rho$ in SI transforms to $\rho$ in Gaussian units. Therefore, to convert your SI Maxwell's Equation $(\phi,\rho)$ to Gaussian units $(\phi^G,\rho^G)$, use the the aforementioned scale factors:
\begin{eqnarray}
\Box\phi &=& \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}\\
\implies \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi\epsilon_0}}\Box\phi^G &=& \frac{\sqrt{4\pi\epsilon_0}\rho^G}{\epsilon_0}\\
\implies \Box\phi^G &=& 4\pi\rho^G
\end{eqnarray}
The transformation using $\sqrt{\mu_0/4\pi}$ applies to the magnetic vector potential, not to electric potential.

Comment: My teacher made a mistake in the notes :P 
Thanks a lot